# Inserting image into a container Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am looking at this template i found on startflutter.com and the full code can be seen below

i try to insert my own image into the circle and it seems there isn't a way to fit the image to fully go into the box (it's always cropped)

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final alucard = Hero(
          tag: 'hero',
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 72.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/alucard.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I would like to insert an image in a container, like so

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alucard = Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
          )
        )
    );
```

But this doesn't work and wont show up, what is wrong with this?

Here is the whole page of code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'home-page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alucard = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 72.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/alucard.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final welcome = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Welcome Alucard',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final lorem = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit condimentum mauris id ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final body = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Colors.blue,
          Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ]),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[alucard, welcome, lorem],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Would increasing the radius of the `CircleAvatar` help your cause?

Comment: I tried that it keeps the same cropping of the image.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more of what you want and what you are actually seeing? Perhaps also share the image you are working with

Comment: All i'm trying to do is insert a full image above the text in  "final welcome" and "final lorem".......the image will show up in the "CircleAvatar" class but when i try using the container it will not show anything at all, and doesn't have a placeholder space where it would be. Ive tried using a bunch of different images for it to show but it won't... i dont think it has to do with the image

Answer (score 82):

Change your container with this will work fine

```
Container(
      height: 120.0,
      width: 120.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
              'assets/assets/alucard.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: how to fit small image in big container in flutter ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
new Container(
  width: 100.00,
  height: 100.00,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
  image: new DecorationImage(
      image: ExactAssetImage('assets/example.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      ),
  ));
```

Make sure you tell flutter where your assets folder is by editing the pubspec.yaml file https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ExactAssetImage-class.html

Answer (score 9):

Passing `BoxFit.fill` to your `Image.asset` should do.

Try this;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'home-page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alucard = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Container(
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage(
                  'assets/alucard.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
            borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final welcome = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Welcome Alucard',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final lorem = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit condimentum mauris id ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final body = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Colors.blue,
          Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ]),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[alucard, welcome, lorem],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying .... argument type "Image" cannot be assigned to parameter type "ImageProvider",   i cannot use Image.asset in backgroundImage

Comment: My bad. Edited now. Check.

Comment: Did this work for you? because i had what you written in my question minus the padding and the borderradius.  When i run that chunk of code you wrote, i still run into the same problem. It doesn't show the image and doesn't leave a place holder where it should be

Comment: The `Container` with the image needs a height and width.

Comment: Set the `Container` height and width as suggested by @AlbertLardizabal. I've also edited my answer setting the container height and width.

Comment: @JacksonPaul Your `Container`'s `width`/`height` should be 2x the `borderRadius` or just make them variables proportional to each other.

Answer (score 8):

Can add image into a container as-
[your_image_folder_path/image_name]

```
Container(
    child:  Image(image: AssetImage("images/logo.png")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
Container(
    height: _height*0.35,
    width: _width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: ExactAssetImage('assets/splash_img.jpeg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
    ),
),
```